# SQL server WHERE between numbers that have a text pre/suffix

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring

I need to return matches that are with a range of serial numbers but the prefix and suffix need to be removed

Ie. I need to search between the below serial numbers but the sequential numbers are only the middle part.

G4A41103801702  -   G4A41113171702

G4A [4110380] 1702  -   G4A [4111317] 1702

I need to exclude the first 3 and last 4 digits and then search between
4110380-4111317

thanks

Comment: when you say "search between" you mean return all records >= 4110380 and <= 4111317? Are these strings always the same length and the required digits always in the same position in the strings? If so then basically you need to use a substring function to find the digits in the expected position and of the expected length, cast it to a number and use it in your where clause. Probably won't be very effficient though due to lack of indexing on those values. If you need to search on these values a lot it might be a good idea to parse them into a separate column at insert-time

Comment: If at all possible you should see about fixing your data structure. This violates 1NF by stuffing multiple values into a single tuple. It causes all sorts of challenges like performance issues and seriously ugly queries for what should be simple. This should be three columns and then a computed column to put them all together.

Comment: ^ what Sean said, many times over.

Comment: Once we've got the rules from you on how to parse the code into its 3 constituent parts, then the aforementioned idea of computed columns is a good idea, but to avoid system changes tou could make 3 computed columns holding the constituent parts, therefore making queries on the values easy and potentially indexable as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

baton, try a variation of the query below:

Replace `id` with the column you want to select.

Replace `tablename` with your actual table name.

Assumes `serialnumber` is the name of the column with the serial to be queried against.

Assumes the length of the serial number is constant.

```
SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE
CAST(SUBSTRING(serialnumber, 4, 7) as int) >= 4110380 AND
CAST(SUBSTRING(serialnumber, 4, 7) as int) <= 4111317
```

As @ADyson mentioned, this will not utilize an index and you should extract this number into a separate indexed column for a more performant query. Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you might want to cast the substring result to int

Comment: Thanks I think Figured it out from this, but If I wanted to exclude the first 3 characters shouldn't the substring start with 4 not 3?)

Comment: @r.baton yes, you're correct, it should. Hopefully Sean will correct the answer at some point

Answer (score 0):

If length is not constant, you can combine `reverse` function twice time to  exclude the `first 3` and `last 4` digits:

```
SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE
substring(reverse(substring(reverse(serialnumber),5)),4) >= 4110380 AND
substring(reverse(substring(reverse(serialnumber),5)),4) <= 4111317
```

test :

```
substring(reverse(substring(reverse('G4A41103801702'),5)),4) ==> '4110380'
```

Comment: No need to cast as INT; this would happen automatically

Answer (score 0):

I'd handle this like so:

```
-- Sample data
DECLARE @table TABLE (col1 VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @table (col1)
VALUES ('G4A41103801702 - G4A41113171702');

-- solution
SELECT 
  c1=SUBSTRING(s.s1,PATINDEX(p.P,s.s1),7), 
  c2=SUBSTRING(s.s2,PATINDEX(p.P,s.s2),7)
FROM   @table AS t
CROSS JOIN  (VALUES('%'+REPLICATE('[0-9]',7)+'%'))  AS p(P)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('-',t.col1)))         AS br(b)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(SUBSTRING(t.col1,1,br.b-1), 
                    SUBSTRING(t.col1,br.b+1,8000))) AS s(s1,s2);
```

**Returns:**

```
c1      c2
------- -------
4110380 4111317
```

You can then use c1 and c2 elsewhere.